# How to correctly apply a RE for obtaining the last name (of a file or folder) from a given path and print it on Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, printing, path, python-re

I have wrote a code which creates a dictionary that stores all the absolute paths of folders from the current path as **keys**, and all of its filenames as **values**, respectively. This code would only be applied to paths that have folders which only contain file images. Here:

```
import os
import re
# Main method
the_dictionary_list = {}

for name in os.listdir("."):
    if os.path.isdir(name):
        path = os.path.abspath(name)
        print(f'\u001b[45m{path}\033[0m')
        match = re.match(r'/(?:[^\\])[^\\]*$', path)
        print(match)
        list_of_file_contents = os.listdir(path)
        print(f'\033[46m{list_of_file_contents}')
        the_dictionary_list[path] = list_of_file_contents
        print('\n')
print('\u001b[43mthe_dictionary_list:\033[0m')
print(the_dictionary_list)
```

The thing is, that I want this dictionary to store only the last **folder names** as keys instead of its **absolute paths**, so I was planning to use this re `/(?:[^\\])[^\\]*$`, which would be responsible for obtaining the last name (of a file or folder from a given path), and then add those last names as keys in the dictionary in the for loop.

I wanted to test the code above first to see if it was doing what I wanted, but it didn't seem so, the value of the `match` variable became `None` in each iteration, which didn't make sense to me, everything else works fine.

So I would like to know what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to rewrite the code above, in case of wanting to apply it only in the current directory (where this program would be found).

```
import os
# Main method

the_dictionary_list = {}

for subdir in os.listdir("."):
    if os.path.isdir(subdir):
        path = os.path.abspath(subdir)
        print(f'\u001b[45m{path}\033[0m')
        list_of_file_contents = os.listdir(path)
        print(f'\033[46m{list_of_file_contents}')
        the_dictionary_list[subdir] = list_of_file_contents
        print('\n')
print('\033[1;37;40mThe dictionary list:\033[0m')
for subdir in the_dictionary_list:
    print('\u001b[43m'+subdir+'\033[0m')
    for archivo in the_dictionary_list[subdir]:
        print("    ", archivo)
print('\n')
print(the_dictionary_list)
```

This would be useful in case the user wants to run the program with a double click on a specific location (*my personal case*)

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend to use the builtin library `pathlib`. It would appear you are interested in the `f.name` part. Here is a cheat sheet.

[image]